# background color on a select tag breaks firefox UI

Tags: css, firefox, user-interface

here is a regular `<select>` box look on firefox (osx):

[image]

if i add the following style to it:

```
form select.error {
    background-color: #FFAAAA;
}
```

it looks like this:

[image]

**question:**
Is there any way to keep the pretty styling and still make it red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "pretty styling" is all a single background image drawn by the OS.  So when you override it, Firefox has to fall back to some other kind of styling...

So no, you can't keep the original look but just change the background color.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reliably style select boxes as browsers tend to stick to the OS's defaults.  Your anser is no, if you only intend on using CSS.

There are jQuery options for styling select boxes available:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Comment: dang. btw, speaking of jquery select box replacements, i wrote a better one than the one you pointed out from 3 years ago: http://programmingdrunk.com/current-projects/dropdownReplacement/